# How to debug an cordova app on iOS7 with XCode 5

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, cordova

I googled but did not find anything.

How can I debug an cordova 3.3.0 app using XCode 5 and a physical iOS7 iPad Retina?

I get a white screen and I have no idea what is happening. Is there an JavaScript error? Is a file missing?

This black box is driving me insane.
I tried jsconsole.com, but the app does not load the external js file.

Are there any tools that can help here? I don't see anything, it's just frustrating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can debug with the desktop safari app, enable the development settings for safari desktop and the web inspector for safari mobile (inside settings app -> safari -> advanced).
Then on the new development tab of desktop safari you'll see your device

Answer (score 1):

To speed up your development and debugging you can use the Ripple Emulator.

[Here](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2013/11/5/Ripple-is-Reborn) you find a good tutorial how to install and use Ripple with Cordova / PhoneGap 3.x

Have fun...